# Storing one single array element in a variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I started learning to code & JavaScript nearly two months ago. And I guess I have now a good knowledge of the basics except arrays. I have a big problem with arrays when it comes to iterating and storing **ONE** single element in a given variable.

For example:

```
function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {
  // Find my place in this sorted array.
  var sorted = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a > b;
  });

  // console.log(sorted);

  var checker = 0;
  var finalResult = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
    checker = num;
    if (checker <= sorted[i]) {
      checker = sorted[i];
      console.log(checker);
      finalResult = arr.indexOf(checker);
    }
  }
    return finalResult;
}



console.log(getIndexToIns([10, 20, 30, 40, 50], 35));
```

In this example, I want to loop over `arr` and whenever the `if` condition is `true` store that value in the `checker` variable. **But** it is storing that value `40` but the loop does not stop, it continues and store the remaining elements in the array also, i.e, `50`.

Please explain to me the concept and how to stop the loop and store that single element when the condition is true.

Comment: You should add a `break;` in your `if` to stop the loop.

Comment: [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) sorts in place, and need not a boolean value, but a value smaller than zero, zero or greater than zero, depending on the wanted order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some annotations

```js
function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {
    var i;                             // declare at top

    arr.sort(function (a, b) {         // sort sorts in situ
        return a - b;                  // return delta, because sort expects
    });                                // numerical values

    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] >= num) {
            break;                     // exit loop on find
        }
    }
    return i;                          // no need for indexOf, index is known
}

console.log(getIndexToIns([10, 20, 30, 40, 50], 35));
console.log(getIndexToIns([10, 20, 30, 40, 50], 100));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a break statement when you want to return from the for loop.

```
function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {
  // Find my place in this sorted array.
  var sorted = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a > b;
  });

  // console.log(sorted);

  var checker = 0;
  var finalResult = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
    checker = num;
    if (checker <= sorted[i]) {
      checker = sorted[i];
      console.log(checker);
      finalResult = arr.indexOf(checker);
      break;
    }
  }
    return finalResult;
}
```